# declared variable as float, but output is coming in integers

Tags: c++, output, xlib

I have written a program using Xlib headers in c++
This is a part of it.

```
XPoint m[5];

m[0].x = 0; m[0].y = 400;
m[1].x = 150; m[1].y = 250;
m[2].x = 250; m[2].y = 300;
m[3].x = 300; m[3].y = 200;
m[4].x = 450; m[4].y = 400;

float slope=(m[2].y-m[1].y)/(m[2].x-m[1].x); cout<<slope<<endl;
```

slope should be 0.5 but it gives 0. Can you please explain why and what's the correct way?? Is it because of the XPoint?? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the members of the `XPoint` are integers, then you are doing integer-arithmetic no matter what type you assign the result to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the members `x` and `y` are of an integral type, so the division is done on integers, which simply truncates the fractional part of the result. In other words, `50 / 100`, which is `0.5`, gets truncated to the `0` you see in your output.

In order to avoid that, you must cast one of the operands to a floating point value, like this:

```
float slope = static_cast<float>(m[2].y-m[1].y)/(m[2].x-m[1].x);
```

Comment: @user3518182 You're welcome. If you like my answer you might consider up voting and/or accepting it.